# How to insert a complex div inside a string in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a `ReactJs` and I have to style a div inside a string

Here is the string I am talking about

```
const instruction1 = <div>XXXXXX: xxxx <div>{state.numbers[0]}</div>, xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

But the outcome is something like this
[image]

But I need the outcome to be like this

[image]

The problem is that I have to use a `div` because there will be multiple elements inside that div.

Why is using the `div` tag mess up the design?

Answer (score 0):

`div` is a block element, it means in the HTML it will look like in a new row. Try to use `span` instead. It will not break the line.

Update: not sure why you need `div` at all. It seems you could put your items directly to the root `div`:

```
<div>XXXXXX: xxxx {state.numbers[0]}, {state.numbers[1]}, xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Comment: I need the div because I will put more numbers, backgroun colors, paddings, ect..

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I wrapped the `div` in a `span` and gave display `inline-block` to that `span`